# what is an "edge disjoint spanning tree"?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

if there are n = 2 vertices in a connected graph, i am supposed to have "n/2 edge disjoint spanning trees". This means i should have 1 edge disjoint spanning tree for a n = 2 graph?

My best guess is that if i remove the only edge between a to b, the connected graph is not disconnected. however, the only result i see from doing this is getting 2 separate disconnected graphs.

please please clarify or define to me what an "edge disjoint spanning tree" means ? When i google the term, I only get a bunch of research papers that I cannot understand. 
thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means that you have a set of $n/2$ spanning trees where *no two trees in the set have an edge in common*. So it is a property of pairs of trees, not a single tree. Thus it is trivially satisfied for the only connected graph on $n=2$ verices.

Comment: for each of the n/2 spanning trees, will it include all of the vertices from the connected graph ? just not all the edges?

Comment: Yes, that's what spanning means.

Comment: thank you very much! i can't upvote your answer because i don't have enough rep, but if i could, i definitely would

Comment: i came to upvote when i had enough rep :) sorry for the delay

Comment: @user1476390 Thanks! If only all new users were so respectful. Welcome to the community.